# Hibernate : Change Hibernate Connection

Tags: java, hibernate, session

Is there a way I can make my connection to the database in `Hibernate` to be `per-session` not `per-request`? Because I have noticed that for every request to in of my pages in the web App the Hibernate Configuration is re-created, and that might affect the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the same SessionFactory without recreating one. So you need to make it static.

Example :

```
public class HibernateUtils{
    private static SessionFactory session;

    private static void createSession(){
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }
    public static Session getSession(){
         if(session == null)
             createSession()
         return session.openSession();
    }
}
```

When you will call "HibernateUtils.getSession()" that will create your session only if it isn't exist

Of course, you need to close session when needed